# Must Understand check Failed for UT secured Service

Tags: web-services, soap, wso2, apache-axis

I have an axis2 service deployed on WSO2 AS 5 which I've secured with UT basic auth using the server. I want to invoke the service with an Axis client. I generated the stub and tried this,

```
        String trustStore = "/home/dumidu/wso2carbon.jks";
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",  trustStore );
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "test123");

        HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator basicAuthentication = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
        basicAuthentication.setUsername("admin");
        basicAuthentication.setPassword("admin");

        OrderProcessorStub ordPros = new OrderProcessorStub();
        ordPros._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, basicAuthentication);                       
        OrderProcessorStub.GetOrder req = new OrderProcessorStub.GetOrder();
        req.setOrdID(1);

        OrderProcessorStub.GetOrderResponse resp = ordPros.getOrder(req);
        System.out.println("resp \t"+resp.get_return());
```

Im getting this error on client side,

> INFO: basic authentication scheme selected
>   Apr 30, 2015 6:02:58 PM org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine receive
>   SEVERE: Must Understand check failed for header http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd : Security
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Must Understand check failed for header http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd : Security
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.checkMustUnderstand(AxisEngine.java:105)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:171)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:364)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
>       at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
>   ....
>   ....

and this on server,

> [2015-04-30 18:02:58,250] ERROR - AxisEngine System error
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: System error
>       at org.wso2.carbon.security.pox.POXSecurityHandler.invoke(POXSecurityHandler.java:303)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>   ....
>   ....

what am i doing wrong here? how can i write an axis client for a service secured with UT in WSO2 AS? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the your error,  It seems to be bug in the product. In this [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3416),  It says that there is an issue with POX handler..  WSO2AS also using same handler and it must be the reason for your issue as well.  In jira it says `If client request does not include empty soap header, that conversion fails with following error`. So as a workaround, you can try with empty SOAP header.

Comment: Thanks Asela. That turned out to be the issue.